# NestedScrollView smoothScrollTo(int x, int y) requires two calls

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

Title explains it all. Any idea why this is happening? To scroll to the top I need to call:

```
mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0)
mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0)
```

Its child is a `LinearLayout` and I have set

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Besides, `smoothScrollTo` is called after a click event. So the scroll view is fully initialized.